# C++ Mac Xcode error: Control may reach end of non-void function

Tags: c++

I am having this error when I Xcode compiles my code the function is
Error: Control may reach end of non-void function

```
// Displays the abilities
pair<string, int> getability(string pclass, int mana, int inte, int level) {
    string input;
    string ability;
    int cost;
    cout << "Choose an ability" << endl;
    if (pclass == "Champion") { // Champion Section
        cost = inte*(level);
        cout << "[1] Cleaving Strike [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Melting Thrust [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Critical Bash [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cost = inte*(level+1);
        cout << "[4] Purify [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cost = inte*(level);
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "1") {
            ability = "cleaving strike";
            if (mana > cost) {
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else if (input == "2") {
            ability = "melting thrust";
            if (mana > cost) {
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else if (input == "3") {
            ability = "critical bash";
            if (mana > cost) {
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else if (input == "4") {
            ability = "purify";
            if (mana > cost) {
                cost = inte*(level+1);
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And this is how I call it, I have currently looked and looked and can't find a method that will fix this. I am using a Mac, and using Xcode. Please help me!

```
tie(action, mana) = getability(pclass, mana, inte, level);
```

Comment: What does `getability` return if `pcclass` isn't `"Champion"` or if `input` isn't 1, 2, 3 or 4?

Comment: If your user input something not in the if-else like for exemple "5" your function does not return anything. In C++ you must always return something (or throw an exception)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are taking `input` as a string. What if the user types anything besides a number 1-4? What about `5`? What about `hello`? You don't handle any of these cases. You can put a return outside of your `if` if you're that certain your user won't mess up, but that won't make your program robust.

I'd suggest changing `input` to be an `int` (you're only looking for integers anyways) and adding a loop to check their input.

```
int input;
cin >> input;

while(input < 0 || input > 4) {
    cout << "BAD INPUT, try again: ";
    cin >> input;
}

//all of your if statements
```

However, the compiler is stupid, as all computers are. It sees you have `if...else if...else if...` and reasons that technically there's still a way we could leave that without going into any of the branches. So at the end of the function, you can add a dummy return:

```
return {"", 0};
```

Answer (score -1):

I think I might have figured it out I made it to return something no matter what I think... New code is below.

```
// Displays the abilities
pair<string, int> getability(string pclass, int mana, int inte, int level) {
    string input;
    string ability;
    int cost;
    cout << "Choose an ability" << endl;
    if (pclass == "Champion") { // Champion Section
        cost = inte*(level);
        cout << "[1] Cleaving Strike [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cout << "[2] Melting Thrust [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cout << "[3] Critical Bash [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cost = inte*(level+1);
        cout << "[4] Purify [" << cost << " mana]" << endl;
        cost = inte*(level);
        cin >> input;
        if (input == "1") {
            ability = "cleaving strike";
            if (mana > cost) {
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            } else {
                ability = "none";
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else if (input == "2") {
            ability = "melting thrust";
            if (mana > cost) {
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            } else {
                ability = "none";
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else if (input == "3") {
            ability = "critical bash";
            if (mana > cost) {
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            } else {
                ability = "none";
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else if (input == "4") {
            ability = "purify";
            if (mana > cost) {
                cost = inte*(level+1);
                mana = mana - cost;
                return {ability, mana};
            } else {
                ability = "none";
                return {ability, mana};
            }
        } else {
            ability = "none";
            return {ability, mana};
        }
    } else {
        ability = "none";
        return {ability, mana};
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I can compile the code and have no error about this. The only reason why I didn't have the else, or default statements cause there was no possible way, for it not to return the values you give.

Comment: Please do not post answers that you aren't certain will work. If you have doubts, research those doubts and include your findings in your answer. About this answer, it seems like a single return statement at the end would do the same thing.

Comment: Yeah didn't think about that